# ¿Como evitar registros en blanco a la db, en los filtros valido el campo empty.. pero aún así los manda

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, pdo

```
<?php 

$errores = '';
$enviado = '';



if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $nombre = strtoupper($_POST['nombre']);
    $apellidopaterno = strtoupper($_POST['apellidopaterno']);
    $apellidomaterno = strtoupper($_POST['apellidomaterno']);
    $telefono = strtoupper($_POST['telefono']);
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $mensaje = strtoupper($_POST['mensaje']);


try{

   $conexion = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebas;charset=utf8', 'root', '');

    }catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo    "Error:" . $e->getMessage();
    }

    try{

        $statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario(nombre,apellidopaterno,apellidomaterno,telefono,correo,mensaje)VALUES( :nombre, :apellidopaterno,:apellidomaterno, :telefono, :correo, :mensaje)");
        $statement->bindParam(':nombre', $nombre);
        $statement->bindParam(':apellidopaterno', $apellidopaterno);
        $statement->bindParam(':apellidomaterno', $apellidomaterno);
        $statement->bindParam(':telefono', $telefono);
        $statement->bindParam(':correo', $correo);
        $statement->bindParam(':mensaje', $mensaje);
        $conexion->beginTransaction();
        $statement->execute();  
        $conexion->commit();    

}catch(Exception $e) {
    $conexion->rollback();
    echo "Error: 0" . $e->getMessage();
}


    if (!empty($nombre)) {
        $nombre = trim($nombre);
        $nombre = filter_var($nombre, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    } else {
        $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa un nombre <br />';
    }


    if (!empty($apellidopaterno)) {
        $apellidopaterno = trim($apellidopaterno);
        $apellidopaterno = filter_var($apellidopaterno, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    } else {
        $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa tu apellido paterno <br />';
    }

    if (!empty($apellidomaterno)) {
        $apellidomaterno = trim($apellidomaterno);
        $apellidomaterno = filter_var($apellidomaterno, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    } else {
        $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa tu apellidomaterno<br />';
    }


    if (!empty($telefono)) {
        $telefono = trim($telefono);
        $telefono = filter_var($telefono, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    } else {
        $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa tu telefono <br />';
    }



    if (!empty($correo)) {
        $correo = filter_var($correo, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

        if(!filter_var($correo, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa un correo valido <br />';
        }
    } else {
        $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa un correo <br />';
    }

    if(!empty($mensaje)){
        $mensaje = htmlspecialchars($mensaje);
        $mensaje = trim($mensaje);
        $mensaje = stripslashes($mensaje);
    } else {
        $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa el mensaje <br />';
    }




    if(!$errores){ $enviado = 'true';
    }

}


require 'index.view.php';



?>
```

Comment: Hola buen día, me refiero a que se introducen los espacios en blanco a mi base de datos, en los filtros abajo de la conexión PDO **if (!empty($variable))** asigne el complemento empty para que no entren datos vacios y efectivamente si no llena el campo aparece un apartado donde especifica que es necesario introducir el campo vacío, pero me recargar la pagina y envía esos datos blanco a mi base de datos... Mi pregunta es cual es el error? no tengo experiencia son mis primeros dos meses en el nucleo backend..

Comment: Si revisas la lógica de tu código podrás ver sin demasiada dificultad que las validaciones son hechas **después del  `INSERT`**, por lo que no tienen ningún sentido ahí, debes hacerlas antes. Además, convendría que valides también del lado del cliente, para evitar que se envíen datos vacíos al servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si revisas la lógica de tu código podrás ver sin demasiada dificultad que **las validaciones son hechas después del INSERT, por lo que no tienen ningún sentido ahí, debes hacerlas antes**. Además, convendría que valides también del lado del cliente, para evitar que se envíen datos vacíos al servidor, pero ese es otro tema.

Propongo este código, explico por orden la lógica que he seguido.

- Establecemos la variable `$errores` a un valor inicial `NULL`. Nos servirá como bandera para saber si adquirió datos o no más adelante en los `if`.
- Vamos a usar operadores ternarios para almacenar de una vez por todas las variables del POST. Aplicaremos ahí todo lo que haya que aplicar a los datos, evitando así la escritura de tanto código redundante. La única función que tiene alguna utilidad aquí sobre los datos es `trim`. Funciones como `filter_var` no sirven de nada aquí. Lo que da solidez al código son las consultas preparadas cuando se trata de insertar datos.
- Antes de hacer el `INSERT` preguntaremos por cada variable. En el operador ternario nosotros le dijimos al código que si alguna variable es vacía le asigne `NULL`. Por tanto en los if podemos evaluar simplemente así: `if (!$variable) { ...`
- Después de evaluar cada variable vamos a preguntar por el estado de nuestra bandera: `if (!$errores){` O sea, si `$errores` es `NULL` como al principio, significa que no hay errores, todo correcto, entonces podemos pasar a insertar.
- Al final de ese bloque cambiamos el estado de `$enviado=TRUE;` Sólo por coherencia de código, le di el valor `FALSE` al principio.

El código sería este:

```
<?php

$errores = NULL;
$enviado = FALSE;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $nombre =          (empty(trim($_POST['nombre'])))          ? NULL : strtoupper($_POST['nombre']);
    $apellidopaterno = (empty(trim($_POST['apellidopaterno']))) ? NULL : strtoupper($_POST['apellidopaterno']);
    $apellidomaterno = (empty(trim($_POST['apellidomaterno']))) ? NULL : strtoupper($_POST['apellidomaterno']);
    $telefono =        (empty(trim($_POST['telefono'])))        ? NULL : $_POST['telefono'];
    $correo =          (empty(trim($_POST['correo'])))          ? NULL : $_POST['correo'];
    $mensaje =         (empty(trim($_POST['mensaje'])))         ? NULL : strtoupper($_POST['mensaje']);

    try{

        $conexion = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebas;charset=utf8', 'root', '');

    }catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo    "Error:" . $e->getMessage();
    }

    try{

        if (!$nombre){
            $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa tu nombre <br />';
        }

        if (!$apellidopaterno){
            $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa tu apellido paterno <br />';
        }

        if (!$apellidomaterno){
            $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa tu apellido materno <br />';
        }

        if (!$telefono){
            $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa tu teléfono <br />';
        }

        if (!$correo){
            $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa tu correo <br />';
        }

        if (!$mensaje){
            $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa un mensaje <br />';
        }

        if (!$errores){

            $statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario(nombre,apellidopaterno,apellidomaterno,telefono,correo,mensaje)VALUES( :nombre, :apellidopaterno,:apellidomaterno, :telefono, :correo, :mensaje)");
            $statement->bindParam(':nombre', $nombre);
            $statement->bindParam(':apellidopaterno', $apellidopaterno);
            $statement->bindParam(':apellidomaterno', $apellidomaterno);
            $statement->bindParam(':telefono', $telefono);
            $statement->bindParam(':correo', $correo);
            $statement->bindParam(':mensaje', $mensaje);
            $conexion->beginTransaction();
            $statement->execute();
            $conexion->commit();
            $enviado=TRUE;
        }

    }catch(Exception $e) {
        $conexion->rollback();
        echo "Error: 0" . $e->getMessage();
    }


}

require 'index.view.php';



?>
```

Hay otras cosas que no quedan claras en el código, como el motivo por el que usas transacciones... ¿es una inserción masiva o el código es un código concurrente que van a usar muchos usuarios al mismo tiempo?

En cualquier caso, creo que este código resuelve el problema aquí planteado. Si tienes otros problemas no dudes en plantearlos abriendo una nueva pregunta.

Si hay alguna duda o error, puedes decirlo en comentarios debajo de esta respuesta.

Comment: Estoy tratan de modificar los true, false y null  pero no encontré el  problema.

Comment: @carlos no entiendo lo que quisiste decir en tu comentario.

Comment: Estoy tratan de modificar los campos true, false y null para ver cual es el error y es que ahora con el código que mando usted me manda los siguientes errores; Los campos vacíos del formulario, si no asigno ningún carácter los arroja como mensaje enviado exitosamente, es decir  que lo esta haciendo al revés. Si yo lleno el formulario por default me dice que tengo errores en todos los campos y no envía ni campos vacíos ni llenos a la base...

Comment: Oh sí, cometí un error: hay que comparar los if negando los valores, por ejemplo : `if (!$nombre){...` ahora corrijo esa parte, @carlos

Comment: Me lo puedo compartir porfavor...

Comment: @carlos he corregido el código, se trataba de poner este símbolo en los  `if` que hay dentro del `try`, porque lo que hay que ir verificando es si alguno de esos valores es nulo para agregar a `$errores` el mensaje correspondiente. Al no usar `!` estaba evaluando al revés.

Comment: Es usted un gran apoyo, aunque no entienda bien aún los conceptos me desespero por no encontrar la solución, tratare de calmar, analizare su código y de verdad muchas gracias se a solucionado.

Comment: @carlos, yo expliqué antes del código punto por punto los elementos esenciales. Al principio uno se pierde un poco al no dominar ciertos conceptos y prácticas, pero con el tiempo ese dominio se va adquiriendo. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda. Me alegro de haberte ayudado a resolver este problema. Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Hola carlos puedes poner en ves de empty puedes poner `strlen($var)` esa funcion te retorna la longitud del texto y así podrás manejar el tamaño minimo de las variables (si lo deseas si no sigue con el empty) a y, otra cosa el `filter_var` y tambien el `trim` va afuera de el `if` esa función a veces te deja los textos en blanco y si dentro del `if` pones esta función puede que te añada textos en blanco.